# angularjs http works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I saw some similiar posts at forum but didn't find solition to my problem. Maybe it's because I'm new to js/angular and that stuff. Here's the thing:

Perfect picture:
I click button  data (some text / numbers) from server are updated and displayed.

My problem is - I get the data only once. Later some other function from jquery.js is called instead of mine.

```
        if ( !(eventHandle = elemData.handle) ) {
        eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
            // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
            // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
            return typeof jQuery !== core_strundefined && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
                jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
                undefined;
        };
```

my code:

controllers.js:

```
    myApp.controller('ajaxController', function($scope, $http, $log){

        $scope.ajaxData={};
        $scope.ajaxData.doClick = function(item, event){

            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'temp/temp.json', params: { 'foobar': new Date().getTime() } }).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.debug(data);
                    $scope.ajaxData = data;
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.debug("not good");
                });
```

index.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ajaxController"> (...)

<button ng-click="ajaxData.doClick(item, $event)">Send Request</button>
percentage: {{$scope.ajaxData.data.cpu}}</br>
usage: {{$scope.ajaxData.total}}</br>
idle: {{$scope.ajaxData.idle}}</br>
```

I can see in chrome console that first request is done and it succeed, later code mentioned above is executed instead and i get no data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your success function you're overwriting the ajaxData with your response

```
$scope.ajaxData = data
```

This means `$scope.ajaxData.doClick` no longer exists. Try binding `doClick` just to your $scope instead.

Comment: You are right! I changed it in different way - instead $scope.ajaxData = data; --> $scope.ajaxData.someData = data.someData; and it works. Thank you.